# getAvailableBlocksLong() * getBlockSizeLong() VS getAvailableBytes()

Tags: java, android, emulation, genymotion

[EDIT] I did make a stupid mistake on my testing. I asked a question here without knowing it.

The answer is, both are the same. But I leave my post here for others.

**What is the difference between 
`getAvailableBlocksLong() * getBlockSizeLong()` and `getAvailableBytes()`?**

I tested myself and got a really strange result on Genymotion.

The values from `getAvailableBlocksLong() * getBlockSizeLong()` and `getAvailableBytes()` are different!

I literally don't get what is happening here.

Does it have something to do only with Genymotion?
Should I just use `getAvailableBytes()` in most cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former gets the number of available memory blocks and multiplies it by the memory block size, the latter just straight up returns the available momery in bytes. Same thing

Comment: That's what I was thinking and that's why I was using one of those randomly so far. But as you can see the result above, on the emulator, only getAvailableBytes() is returning the value which seems to be more correct. I'm not sure this is just an issue with Genymotion or something.. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: I recommend using the latter one because it is easy to work with and more common, the former inspects the device's memory blocks and some might contain data partially, so they will not report as free blocks, that's why you get a smaller number for the former one. It is just my assumption for the discrepancy however.

Comment: You might think the value was typo but it's not. The latter one is WAY smaller. The former is reporting wrong values on Genymotion, I guess. The method getTotalBytes() returns 5284429824 and this is much smaller than the value got from the former.. I don't know the reason because many people are using the former method.. Anyways I'm going to use getAvailableBytes() as you said. +1 for trying to help me :)

Comment: My bad.. I made a stupid mistake. I reused cached one in my code. You're right, both return the exactly same value. Thanks!