# How much memory is a block?

Tags: android, memory, block

The documentation says that the results from [`getAvailableBlocksLong()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html#getAvailableBlocksLong()) is the same as: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/statvfs.htm

Are `blocks == bytes`?

Comment: Note that there's also a `getBlockSizeLong` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your question:

> Are blocks == bytes?

Not quite.

[`getAvailableBlocksLong()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html#getAvailableBlocksLong()) retrieves the number of blocks that are free on the file system and available to applications. Whereas [`getAvailableBytes`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html#getAvailableBytes()) retrieves the number of bytes that are free on the file system and available to applications.

Which, according to the Q&A [getAvailableBlocksLong() * getBlockSizeLong() VS getAvailableBytes()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35395931/6613600) are related by:

`getAvailableBlocksLong()` * [`getBlockSizeLong()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html#getBlockSizeLong()) = `getAvailableBytes()`